# Google URL Tags Showing in Global Messages

Tags: magento2, global-messages

A strange error I noticed on my Magento 2.2 site yesterday, When I create a URL with google tag generator and then click the link through to the page the campaign tags appear in what I believe is the global messages area of the product pages. under cookie messages.

I can't just remove the globabl message area as there are other messages like added to cart or quote success message appearing which I require.

How can  I stop the cookies messages from appearing in the global message area with out effecting the other success / fail messages ?

**E.g.** 
If i create the link :

> https://burtonsveterinary.com/vetair-mobile-dental-unit-offer.html?utm_source=Website&utm_medium=Banner&utm_campaign=Sale&utm_content=dentalPromo

and then go on the front end page, it displays :

> "utm_source=Website&utm_medium=Banner&utm_campaign=Sale&utm_content=dentalPromo"

above the page image.

Any help would be great

Thanks

Comment: Where do you want to display this link and how did you to display it like this ?

Comment: I dont wish to display the  cookie message "utm_source=Website&utm_medium=Banner&utm_campaign=Sale&utm_content=dentalPromo" it is being displayed and I want to stop it from being displayed on the frontend of product pages ?

Comment: Ok, basically this google link doesn't add the param in cookie messages, check your product file

Answer (score 0):

david actually problem is not in the url you are generating. problem is you are printing querysting mistakenly in

[image]

You have to open this template and remove this printing code.

Comment: Thanks , do you know the template location? and what the printing code i need to remove?

Comment: actually its depend on template you are using, you can find particular template by enabling template path hints for a second. It will let you know the path in which this issue present.

https://magecomp.com/blog/enable-template-path-hints-in-magento-2/

Comment: Let me know if still have an issue?

Comment: if you are unable to find it give me your sits credentials to me in private message I will fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice and kind offer , currently I have a server issue where I cant get into development mode, so looks like I will need to fix this first :( Thanks though!

Comment: ok please accept & up-vote when you fix issue.